# Capacitor Electrolyte

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

I am trying to make a simple, cheap, and effective electrolytic capacitor that I could use the design for multiple projects. What would be a good electrolyte and plate material that I could find at home?  I am striving for as much capacitance as possible. Thanks much!

Comment: Just to be sure, because it is not completely clear: are you trying to build an electrolytic capacitor yourself using common materials?

Comment: Yes. I was hoping to make a cheap but effective design for many projects.

Comment: What would you consider "effective"? What's your goal here?

Comment: I'm with @duskwuff here: what's your goal? If you are just experimenting (like "I want to verify that a capacitor is not a tiny black box, but it can be made as described in Physics books"), that's ok. ....

Comment: ... On the other hand, if you want to find a way to create cheap and practical capacitors (i.e. usable in common hobbyists circuits), then that's not going to work out. Even the cheapest and lowest quality capacitors found on ebay will probably outperform your design: smaller, cheaper, more reliable and they won't make you waste time (time better spent in doing, for example, more interesting circuit design or experimentation).

Comment: BTW: mass market technology is almost impossible to beat with home-made stuff nowadays. And remember the most valuable resource you have is *your* time. Consider this: if you spend an hour working on a small job (say babysitting or cutting grass in the neighborhood) you will probably earn enough money to buy a couple hundred "el cheapo" electrolytic caps on ebay!

Answer (score 2):

There's typically a spacer made of paper saturated in electrolyte between the oxide layers, so the thin (nm) dielectric layers are protected. Al2O3 is also quite hard- it is used as an abrasive.

You could try dissolving some sal ammoniac in ethylene glycol for a home made electrolyte, but I'm not sure it would work well. Or squeeze the juice out of some commercial capacitors.

Comment: Does it matter if the salmiak (NH4Cl) is contaminated with sugar?  That stuff is easily available in Finland: https://www.fazer.fi/globalassets/global/fazer-fi/tuotteet/tuotemerkit/pantteri/pantteri-uusi-pussi-860x390.jpg

Comment: @OskarSkog Sugar is not ionic so it may not, but this is pretty speculative. A brick of NH4Cl can also be used to clean soldering iron tips in stained glass work.

Comment: Could I possibly use something else than ethylene glycol? I'm looking something for easily accessible and inexpensive.

Comment: Undiluted automotive antifreeze (not the non-toxic stuff, not the pre-diluted stuff) may be close to pure ethylene glycol. Read the MSDS.